# Error Undefined property: codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente error, y ni idea de porque (soy nuevo en codeigniter):

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: cPersona::$mPersona

Filename: controllers/cPersona.php

Line Number: 29

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\cPersona.php
Line: 29 ($this->mPersona->guardar_persona($param);)

Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

**Controlador( cPersona)**

```
<?php 



 class cPersona extends CI_Controller {

 function _construct()
 {

    parent:: _construct();
    $this->load->model('mPersona'); // llamamos al modelo mPersona con esta 
    linea
  }


  public function index(){
    $this->load->view('persona/vPersona');
   }

  public function guardar_persona(){        


     $param['rut_per'] = $this->input->post('rut_per');
     $param['pnombre'] = $this->input->post('pnombre');
     $param['snombre'] = $this->input->post('snombre');
     $param['apellido_pa'] = $this->input->post('apellido_pa');
     $param['apellido_ma'] = $this->input->post('apellido_ma');
     $param['correo_per'] = $this->input->post('correo_per');

     $this->mPersona->guardar_persona($param);




     }


     }




     ?>
```

**Modelo (mPersona)**

```
     <?php


     class mPersona extends CI_Model
     {

     function __construct()
     {
     parent:: __construct();
     }

     public function guardar_persona($param)
    {

    $campos= array(

    'rut_per' => $param['rut_per'],
    'pnombre' => $param['pnombre'],
    'snombre' => $param['snombre'],
    'apellido_pa' => $param['apellido_pa'],
    'apellido_ma' => $param['apellido_ma'],
    'correo_per' => $param['correo_per'] 
     //en el ultimo parametro ya no se usa una coma

     );
     //fin del array

     $this->db->insert('personas',$campos);


     }


     }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el controlador te has olvidado de poner un _ y quitar un espacio

```
 function __construct() 
 {

parent::__construct(); //aqui faltaba un _ y sobraba un espacio
$this->load->model('mPersona'); // llamamos al modelo mPersona con esta 
linea
}
```

Por lo cual el modelo mPersona no se estaba cargando

Comment: Gracias j0se, no me había dado cuenta....siempre me pasan errores así :C algún consejo para que no me suceda?(estoy por comenzar mi practica profesional, y no quiero romperme la cabeza por no fijarme que escribí algo mal...)

Comment: Practicar y practicar y practicar...me costo verlo, estaba todo bien.... hasta que salto la liebre. Por cierto si la respuesta te ha servido marcala como valida para que si alguien busca algo similar y cae aquí ya tenga medio camino andado. De todas formas si usas un ide como aptana, sublime o similar se te pondrán colores y veras los fallos de este tipo con mas facilidad